# Linphone Android implementation example

Tags: android, linphone

I am trying to develop an app for Android that connects to a SIP server. I made some research and I found out that linphone is one of the best solution for that ( i need video call ).

I downloaded the sdk and now I don't know where to start from.

A couple of examples will be very usefull.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Everything the above users suggested did not work, at least to me.

The sample code provided by https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android is not even compatable with their newest android SDK.

The sdk documentation provided on their official web page is merely just a javadoc without any explanation, only three lines of code provided.

The only solution that worked was using the below library.

https://github.com/forever4313/EasyLinphone

The guy who made this library deserves a prize from somewhere.

This requires the linphone SDK 3.x. It's not compatable with 4.x versions currently available.

You can get it from here.

https://linphone.org/releases/android/

liblinphone-android-sdk--no-nonfreecodecs-video-3.2.6-23-g85f3b9a.zip

The above file worked great for me.

Import the aars following this youtube tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTgbcblEfX0

Use the EasyLinphone library to do whatever you want.

Comment: This is the best answer here, my  friend I have spent 8 days trying to use the official liblinphone library, you just saved my life... thanks

Comment: @C Williams if you think of loging in and out for multiple users per phone, you must modify some of the codes. 
1. You should overwrite the config files when you login. If not, it will try to register all of your sip ids.
2. The service destroy logic will crash if you don't edit the onDestroy method.
I will update the code changes on the answer above.

Comment: Hi, Please help with the updated code, and do you know where I can find a video tutorial that helps with the basic stuff such as Registration and Calling? Where is the location of the config file sir?

Comment: @C Williams I'll update the code soon. The EasyLinphone seems to cover the video stuff, but never tried it myself.

Comment: @March3April4 I need Your help regarding Linphone' latest library

Comment: @Solaiman Hossain Sorry, It took me a while to get back to this issue. I haven't tried the latest library.

Comment: @March3April4 : i have download and build the android project from the above given git hub. How am i suppose to test this. asking a username password and a domain. is there is any test account. i didn't get why to use ndk and all.

Comment: @DKV You should have a MVOIP server such as Asterisk. The id and passwords are configured there. While doing this project, I had other people doing that kind of stuff, so I really can't give you more specific details. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Besides linphone its own website and the README.md,

Check out the following two links: 
http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html

Make sure you are using a Linux or Mac to build! Especially for the native .so libs for Android. I spent quite a lot futile time trying get the building down on Windows.

After ./prepare.py and make with success use Android Studio and Xcode to build the final application, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the open source version, that they have.

https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android

This uses liblinphone to comunicate with the SIP service.